# Get Stock Market Data using Python

Tags: python, json, live-streaming

I want to fetch live data from url: ***https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/live-equity-market*** using a python code.

The output I am expecting is,

| Symbol | LTP | Open | High | Low |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NIFTY 50 | 12,345.00 | 19,744.85 | 19,798.65 | 19,657.50 |
| ABCD | 12,345.00 | 18,722.25 | 17,598.45 | 17,457.50 |

Comment: What have you tried? Is there an API to connect to? Why tag python2 and python3, which do you want? Maybe you can start here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have tried with python yfinance, but there I have to mention the symbol names. It doesn't solve the purpose. I want some solution which should return all the stock details available at the given url.

Comment: There is no such thing.  There are hundreds of thousands of equity ticker symbols world-wide.  These companies offer summaries as a free service.  They've invested heavily into building site like this, and they don't want you piggybacking off of their years of work.  If you want to pay for a service, perhaps you could find this.